# django_select2, Model object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, modelform

I'm getting a "'Document' object is not iterable" error when this form is submitted. It works if 'document' is just taken from the model rather than written with the select2 package. It's extremely similar to the example code from the django_select2 package. I've tried making it Document.objects.all() instead, and that didn't work either.

models.py

```
class Individual(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, verbose_name='ID')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    entered_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def _name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = 'name_of_database'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

class Document(models.Model):
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = 'name_of_database'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.document_name

class DocLog(models.Model):

    individual = models.ForeignKey('Individual', to_field='id', null=True)
    fiscal = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    document = models.ManyToManyField(Document, max_length=50,    
    verbose_name='Document Title')
    date_received = models.DateField(editable=True, verbose_name='Date Received')
    doc_notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Document Notes')
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    entered_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = 'name_of_database'
        verbose_name = 'Document Log'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.individual.id
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django_select2 import *
from .models import DocLog, Document

#Document Select2 class
class DocumentChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = Document.objects
    search_fields = ['document_name__icontains',]

#New document form
class NewDocument(forms.ModelForm):

    document = DocumentChoices()

    class Meta:

        model = DocLog
        fields = ('individual', 'fiscal', 'document', 'date_received', 'doc_notes')

        widgets = {
            'individual': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined ManyToManyField in your Model, in Modelform ManyToManyField is represented by django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField, which is a MultipleChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet.

So instead of using AutoModelSelect2Field you use [AutoModelSelect2MultipleField](http://django-select2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref_fields.html?highlight=automodelselect2multiplefield#django_select2.fields.AutoModelSelect2MultipleField)

for your case

```
#Document Select2 class
class DocumentChoices(AutoModelSelect2MultipleField):
    queryset = Document.objects
    search_fields = ['document_name__icontains',]
```